# EmberJS Server side paginations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, pagination

I want to make a grid with server side pagination sorting and filtering, i have all set on the back-end with Rails and active-models-serializers, currently i managed to do it with datatables.net plugin and plain JS/JQuery, but ATM i want to migrate the front-end to EmberJS, till the moment all i can find are some examples with ArrayController and Pageable-Mixings doing some kind of client side pagination which don't work for me on this application. Is there any datables.net replacement in the EmberJS ecosystem?, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables.net has been around for a while and is pretty full-featured. I'm not aware of any 1-1 replacement in the EmberJS ecosystem. That said, [ember-table](http://addepar.github.io/ember-table/) is pretty awesome and might be a good fit for your app. For sure it can render a grid backed by server-side pagination/sorting/filtering.

To see how pagination works, checkout the [table-with-ajax](https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table/blob/master/examples/table_ajax/table_ajax.coffee#L15-L25) example. It uses the github api to lazy-load one page (30 rows) of data at a time. I've not tried but you could extend that example to support server-side sort and filter by:

Resetting the content array whenever your sort/filter properties change:

```
content: Ember.computed ->
  App.TableAjaxExample.LazyDataSource.create
    content: new Array(@get('numRows'))
.property 'numRows', 'sort', 'filter'
```

and then using those properties when requesting data from your server:

```
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/emberjs/ember.js/events?page=#{page}&per_page=30&sort=#{sort}&filter=#{filter}&callback=?"
```

Comment: It is a shame that EmberJS doesn't count with a versatile table as AngularJS does or Backbone, I will give it a try to ember-table but as far as I see the docs are not good, also I have my doubts with the theme customization and the effort I will have to make to adequate it to my use case. I appreciate your help in any case, thanks for everything.